# How to add a custom attribute to standard thymeleaf dialect 'th'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my spring MVC application I am trying to create a custom thymeleaf dialect to convert ASCII string to text. I am able to create the dialect with prefix other than `'th'`. But if I try to use `'th'` as prefix, then the server throwing the following runtime exception.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: When using SpringTemplateEngine, at least one of the configured dialects must be or extend org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect.
org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine.initializeSpecific(SpringTemplateEngine.java:147)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:831)
org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:203)
org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Basically What I need to achieve here is to create a custom dialect like this `th:asciitext`. Any help will be much appreciated.

NB: If somebody needs to look into the code which I already tried, feel free to ask in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could find is by extending `SpringTemplateEngine` (it is designed to be extended). After that, replace the default`SpringTemplateEngine` by the new template engine. Check out the code below:

**MySpringTemplateEngine**

```
public class MySpringTemplateEngine extends SpringTemplateEngine {

   private Set<IProcessor> additionalProcessors;

   public Set<IProcessor> getAdditionalProcessors() {
      return additionalProcessors;
   }

   public void setAdditionalProcessors(Set<IProcessor> additionalProcessors) {
      this.additionalProcessors = additionalProcessors;
   }

   @Override
   public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      super.afterPropertiesSet();
      Map<String, IDialect> dialectsByPrefix = this.getDialectsByPrefix();
      StandardDialect springDialect = (StandardDialect) dialectsByPrefix.get("th");
      springDialect.setAdditionalProcessors(additionalProcessors);
   }
}
```

**application-context.xml**

```
  <bean id="templateEngine" class="path.to.extended.engine.MySpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="additionalProcessors">
      <set>
          <bean class="path.to.your.processor.AttrProcessor1" />
          <bean class="path.to.your.processor.AttrProcessor2" />
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this URL: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html

I think you have a similar scenario as Scenario 1.

Comment: I already referred this link. It is not given any example to refer

Comment: Here is their customized extrathyme application (they are using spring mvc): https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-extrathyme.git I agree that this could take some time wrapping our head around but this is where I started.

Comment: This example is already available in the link which you mentioned in the answer. But it is all about dialects which is having a prefix other than 'th'

Comment: th is a standard prefix used by thymeleaf standard dialect. I am not sure if you have a lot of customization options here.

Comment: According to scenario 1 of the above link, it is possible, but they are not given any example for that.

Comment: Oh! is it. I had no idea. I went by the books :(